# Split step Fourier propagation - Beam propagation method

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, physics, image-scaling

Hello I'm having a difficulty using the split step Fourier method. Assuming I want to propagate a Gaussian in free space, I'm supposed to use:

```
A(x,z) = F^-1 [exp((i*k^2*z)/(2*k_0))* F[A(x,0)]]
```

where F is the Fourier and F^-1 is the inverse Fourier.

What I want to do is plot I(x,z=0), I(x,z=3) and the intensity distribution in the x-z plane.

I tried doing it numerically (plotting I(x,z=0), I(x,z=3)) using the following code:

```
lambda = 0.5*10^-6;
k0 = 2*pi/lambda;
w = 10*10^-6;
N=500;
a=0.4*10^-4;
dx=a/N;
x = -a/2:dx:a/2-dx;
Dk_x = 2*pi*N/a;
dk_x=2*pi/a;
k_x=-Dk_x/2:dk_x:Dk_x/2-dk_x;
N = (k_x.^2)/(2*k0);
z = 0:(5*10^-3)/length(N):5*10^-3;
z(end) = [];
% A0 = A(x,z=0)
A0 = exp(-x.^2/w^2);
I_0 = A0.*conj(A0);
% F_A0 is the fourier of A0
F_A0 = fft(A0);
% A3 = A(x,z=3)
A3 = ifft(exp(1i*N*3).*F_A0);
I_3 = A3.*conj(A3);
figure
plot(x,I_3,x,I_0)
```

However, I_3 is not what I expected to receive which is another Gaussian of smaller intensity.

Also, I'm unsure how I'd plot the intensity distribution in the x-z plane. They suggest using the imagesc function which I suppose I'd use it like:

```
imagesc(x,z, abs(ifft(exp(1i*N.*z).*F_A0).^2)
```

but the third argument, which is supposed to be a matrix, is a vector in what I've written..

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the propagation is along z, the gaussian you want to propagate is 1D, the split step needs a for loop where you propagate each time with a small dz...

Comment: but for I(x,z=3), am I not looking at a single z?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. I shall try now and update. thank you!

Comment: I think you mixed up the spatial dimension of the gaussian x, and the propagation dimension z. z should be someything like `z=linspace(0,3,Nz)`

Comment: From what I understand now, I think the whole z component that I've written is quite random, and I_3 doesn't really represent the the intensity at the output face, since all I've done was take the initial gaussian, and just z=3 and plug them into the equation called A3. I didn't really propagate the beam. What I'm going to try and do now is iterate over z like you said and take the step before as the psi0 each time. I hope this'll work. I will update once I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an example for a split step free Gaussian propagation:

```
N=2^9; % x grid points
L=100; % box length
dx=L/N; %position grid interval
x=(-L/2+1/N):dx:L/2; %define position grid (centered around origin)

dk=2*pi/L; %momentum grid interval
k=(-N/2+1:1:N/2).*dk; %define momentum grid

A_z=exp(-x.^2); % initial gaussian
dz=0.01; % propagation step
z=0:dz:3; % propagation vector

% do the propagation using split step
for n=1:numel(z)
    A_z=ifft(fftshift(  exp(1i*k.^2*dz).*fftshift(fft(A_z))  ));
    I_z(n,:)=abs(A_z).^2;
end

imagesc(x,z,I_z)
xlim([-20 20]);
xlabel('x'); ylabel('z')
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much. In what I tried doing now I did almost the same thing but in my loop I happened to save only the last iteration of the intensity and so I was receiving a vector of I(x,z=3)..                                 I tried doing something with your code and plugging in the numbers (wavelength, k0, etc) from my original code above and I'm just getting a green screen. What could be the problem here?

Comment: you need to use consistent units (say microns) , I dont know what numbers you actually use and why, but check that carefully. I'd start by checking that what you input is indeed a non zero vector. From seeing your example I have a feeling (and forgive me for being blunt) that you dont understand what these parameters mean.

Comment: I think I got it working now. Thank you so much for the help bla!

Comment: glad to help, please "accept" the answer... (on the left side)

Comment: Another question, if I may. I'm having trouble propagating the beam in a medium that has a refractive index that is both dependent of x and z - n(x,z)=1+f(x,z) where f(x,z) is 1 when |x|<5/(0.5+z/5000) and 0 otherwise. I know how to propagate it when the refractive index is dependent only of x - n(x). There's an extra phase before the ifft of exp(-i*k0/n0*dn*dz). However, I'm having trouble with this. I thought of running two loops for each x and z and fill up a matrix for n(x,z) but then that wouldn't help with it. Any idea?

Comment: the loop is only on z, think that you can replace z with time. x is your spatial coordinate. and the "splitting" takes your f(x) to f(k) and back to f(x) using fft because the dispersion is expressed in k space. So for implementing a z-dependant operation in x coordinate,  you need an intermediate step, where you split the operator to have the forms `exp(i k^2/2 dz/2) exp(i f(x,z) dz) exp(ik^2/2 dz/2)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. I'm not dealing with free space anymore. I now have an extra term for the index of refraction of the form n=n0+dn(x). The general solution taken to this is:                      A_z=exp(-i*dn*dz).*ifft(fftshift(  exp(1i*k.^2*dz).*fftshift(fft(A_z))  ));              However, dn is not dn(x) but dn(x,z). I'm not sure why what you suggested is how it needs to be done. How would I deal with exp(-i*dn*dz)? The same way (exp(-i*dn(x,z)*dz))?

Comment: Also, how will I check this f(x,z) and where? I mean, over each iteration, it's going to have the same value since the condition would be something like abs(x) < 5/(0.5+dz/5000), right?